# Does Ursula Downs get a free re-roll every turn?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-mountains-madness

Ursula Downs, from the *Mountains of Madness* expansion to *Eldritch Horror*, has the special ability:

> Once per round, you or another investigator on your space may spend 1 less Focus to pay for an effect.

One of the effects that an investigator can use a Focus token for is to re-roll a die during a test. This costs 1 Focus.

Does this mean that Ursula can pay 0 Focus to re-roll one die, once per round? And if so, does she need to "prove she could pay", i.e., have 1 Focus in hand, or is it just free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just free. You may pay one less so you may pay zero to reroll. This is different from a situation such as "when an investigator would gain a clue, gain an extra clue" which is somewhat the wording you are looking for where a conditional would require something before adding a bonus to it.